# Prove that an undirected connected graph $G$ contains an Euler circuit by some properties of its fundamental cut-set matrix and connectivity.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees, eulerian-path

Let $G$ be an undirected connected graph. $\forall v∈V(G)$, $G-v$ (remove the node and all of its relevant edges from the graph) is still a connected graph. Besides, the fundamental cut-set matrix $S$ of $G$ has an even number of ones in each of its rows. Prove that there is an Eulerian circuit in graph $G$.

I have come across the problem and thought about it for quite a long time, but the progress I have yet made is still very little. Here is what I have tried:

First, from the first condition given, I find that every node in the graph should have a degree $d\ge2$, for otherwise by deleting the only node it connects one can split the graph into two separate parts. Also, it tells me that each node is on a circuit. However, I have no idea how to make further use of it.

Then, I tried to analyze the answer to see if the proposition can be reduced to a simpler one. Let the adjacent matrix be $B$, the fundamental loop matrix be $$C=\begin{pmatrix}I & C_f\end{pmatrix}, $$ and the fundamental cut-set matrix be $$S=\begin{pmatrix}S_f & I\end{pmatrix}. $$ Denote the vectors with all one's be $\vec{1}$ (for convenience, I omit the dimension), and assign directions for the edges (it suffices to prove that a certain distribution of directions leads to an Eulerian circuit). Eulerian circuit exists if and only if each node has the same amount of in-degree and out-degree, i.e., $$B\cdot\vec{1}=\vec{0}. $$ Given that $BC^T=0$, I thought it might suffice to prove that $\vec{1}\in \mathcal{R}(C^T)$, i.e., $$\vec{1}= C_f^T\cdot\vec{1}=-S_f\cdot\vec{1}$$ since the left part $I$ of $C$ ensures that we have to take the summation of the rows to create a $\vec{1}$. This is equal to $$S\cdot\vec{1}=\begin{pmatrix}S_f & I\end{pmatrix}\cdot\vec{1}=S_f\cdot\vec{1}+\vec{1}=\vec{0}. $$ Therefore, all I need to do is to show each row of $S$ sum up to 1, which means that every cut-set of $G$ has the same amount of edges with the same direction with the cut-set and with the opposite, i.e., "there is an equal number of edges pointing toward different directions in arbitrary cut-set".

That's all my progress now. I have no idea what I can derive from the condition "the fundamental cut-set matrix $S$ of $G$ has an even number of ones in each of its rows." I even don't know whether I am on the right track. Is there anyone who can help me out?

The question is from a book (戴一奇. (1995). *图论与代数结构*) about Graph Theory and Algebraic Structure (used as the textbook in our Discrete Math course). It is Problem 13 on Exercise 3.

Note. There is a similar question posted a while before by another ([Prove that there is an Euler circuit in graph G](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4412885/1041317)), but the question seems to have not very much detailed explanation and still no answers yet. So I decided to rephrase it and post it again.

Comment: For starters, your graph is undirected, so in-degree and out-degree are not defined. Instead you want to prove that every vertex has even degree.

Comment: It's hard to find a definition of the fundamental cut-set matrix online. Is "the fundamental cut-set matrix has an even number of ones in each row" equivalent to "every fundamental cut-set has an even number of edges"?

Comment: @JLinsta Going by "it suffices to prove that a certain distribution of directions leads to an Eulerian circuit" the plan appears to be to make the graph directed first in such a way that there is a directed Eulerian circuit. Once we've done that, in-degree and out-degree are defined. I am not convinced this is a good plan, but it's not inherently contradictory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definitions are new to me, so let me repeat them to see if they are correct.

We have an undirected connected graph $G$ and we've chosen a particular spanning tree $T$ of $G$. For every edge $e \in E(T)$, there is a corresponding *fundamental cut-set*: the set of all edges of $G$ between the two components of $T-e$.

Assuming the rows of the fundamental cut-set matrix give the fundamental cut-sets, the condition we are given is that every fundamental cut-set has an even number of edges.

---

In a graph with an Eulerian circuit, *all* cut-sets have an even number of edges: if the Eulerian circuit starts on one side of the cut-set, it must cross an even number of times to return where it started, and these crossings use every edge of the cut-set once. Conversely, if all cut-sets in a graph have an even number of edges, then in particular, all vertex degrees are even: the set of edges out of a vertex is a cut-set! So a connected graph is Eulerian **if and only if** all cut-sets have an even number of edges.

So it makes sense to try to prove this statement from the weaker statement that all *fundamental* cut-sets have an even number of edges.

**Theorem.** Every cut-set is a symmetric difference of fundamental cut-sets.

**Proof.** Take an arbitrary cut-set $E(X,Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ partition $V(G)$. We'll show that $E(X,Y)$ is the symmetric difference of all the fundamental cut-sets given by edges in $E(T) \cap E(X,Y)$.

To see this, let $vw$ be any edge of $G$. The fundamental cut-sets containing $vw$ are exactly the ones given by edges on the unique $v-w$ path in $T$. Therefore the symmetric difference we're taking contains $vw$ iff an odd number of edges on this path cross between $X$ and $Y$. This happens iff $v$ and $w$ are on different sides of the cut, which happens iff $vw \in E(X,Y)$. $\qquad\square$

If two sets $A,B$ both have an even number of elements, then their symmetric difference $(A\cup B) - (A \cap B)$ also has an even number of elements, because $$|A \cup B| - |A \cap B| = (|A| + |B| - |A \cap B|) - |A \cap B| = |A|+|B|-2|A\cap B|$$ and all three terms of the final expression are even. By induction, the symmetric difference of any number of even sets is even. So if all fundamental cut-sets are even, then by the argument above, all cut-sets are even, and we are done.